# How can I GeoCode a table of addresses in SQL Server automatically?

Tags: sql-server, geocode

Is there a way to geocode a table of addresses so that latitude and longitude columns can be updated with the correct details.

Ideally I would like a system that will operate every so often, geocoding any address that did not have a lat / long.
Currently there are areound 30,000 addresses in said table.

Thanks in advance

Edit

These are indeed postal addresses for the UK area.

Comment: Will this help you? http://www.maxmind.com/app/geoip_country

Comment: Are these postal addresses? If so, For what locale(s) do you need to geocode the addresses for?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using SQL CLR to write a stored procedure where the lookup can be saved to the address table. Generally this s easy using google web service. If you require high volume there is a fee but the free limit is quite high.

Then you could run an agent job to call the sproc which would on process adressez that were not prevously geocoded.